# Cannot get readable USSD return message

Tags: python, gsm, ussd

I am doing a program to check the balance of the sim, I using the module GSM A6, and here is my python code for that:

```
port.write('AT+CMGF=0'+'\r\n')
time.sleep(2)
port.write('AT+CSCS="HEX"'+'\r\n')
time.sleep(2)
port.write('AT+CUSD=1'+'\r\n')
time.sleep(2)
port.write('AT+CUSD=1,"*101#",15'+'\r\n')
print('Waiting....')
time.sleep(5)
reply = port.read(port.inWaiting())
```

And here is what it return:

AT+CMGF=0

OK

AT+CSCS="HEX"

OK

AT+CUSD=1

OK

AT+CUSD=1,"*101#",15

OK

+CUSD: 1, "D8B41B344687DF20580C879BC56AB8586EA6A02E873A50CCE68AE17264450CD4AC8741E7771A4445BFC369903D0C9A36A70A19A8590F83CEEF348818A687153350B31E0691D36334C85E0739D1E131688C7E2B68A0633A9C06D1E56910F2495500" ,15

I try to translate the hex return message to normal text via online tool like http://www.convertstring.com/vi/EncodeDecode/HexDecode
but what I get is something like that: Ø´4Fß XÅj¸Xn¦ .:PÌæárdEÔ¬AçwDE¿Ãi=6§
¨YÎï4¦3P³Óc4È^9Ñá1h~+h c:ÑåiòIU

Is something wrong with my USSD code, or I have to convert the hex value return with what technique to the readable message ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that, the problem is because I using the wrong tool to convert my HEX value, this one is the correct one:

http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288

Try too convert with USSD Entry/Display with this tool, I got what I need